# How to trigger a job based on external event

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am using spring batch. I have an ETL process that writes records to a DB and after it completes the ETL process, it will also write a ***FLAG*** to PROCESS_COMPLETE table.

Now, I'd like my spring job to trigger once **when both the below conditions are true**

1. It is past 5 PM and
2. The ***FLAG*** has been written in PROCESS_COMPLETE table

Appreciate if someone can suggest how to achieve the above using spring batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using Quartz for this.  The actual triggering the start of a job is not Spring Batch's responsibility.  Using Quartz you can create a custom trigger that will fire when both the time and database conditions are met.

Comment: +1 can you provide any link to tutorial on creating custom triggers. i tried googling but didn't find much.